# Laravel 4.2: Convert a SQL select statement to Eloquent statement

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have the following DB::select statement:

```
DB::select("SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS orders_count FROM order_book as ob WHERE session_id='".$session_id."' GROUP BY user_id");
```

Which its result will be something like:

```
[{
"user_id": 2,
"orders_count": 6
},
{
"user_id": 340,
"orders_count": 83
},
{
"user_id": 341,
"orders_count": 88
}]
```

**what is the equivalent statement using the Eloquent model?**

This is what I have so far:

```
Order::whereSession_id($session_id)->select('user_id','Count(*)')->groupBy('user‌​_id')->get();
```

Comment: I tried this one: Order::whereSession_id($session_id)->select('user_id','Count(*)')->groupBy('user_id')->get();  but not working

Comment: Please, do not put relevant part of the question, e.g. your attempt to solve the question itself, inside comments. Just put the above code as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Order::select('user_id', DB::raw('count(*) as orders_count'))
     ->where('session_id', $session_id)
     ->groupBy('user‌​_id')
     ->get();
```

You need to use `DB::raw` when using `count` in your query's select, because otherwise it will get quoted by PDO.

Answer (score 1):

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                    ->orderBy('user_id', 'desc')
                    ->groupBy('count')
                    ->get();
```

Comment: Please provide a bit of a description about your answer such as why it works or a link to any reference material that supports your answer. try not to post just code - that doesn't help the community.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to get the wanted result in one single call.
You have to count the orders in a loop for every single user.

**You can use the query builder is this case, but not Eloquent.**

Comment: The downvote was because you stated (in bold after the edit) that you **can't use Eloquent**, when in fact you can. Eloquent uses the Query Builder when doing queries so you have all the methods you need from the Query Builder, but you can still have the Eloquent syntax and all its benefits.